# What does "bind" and "binding" mean in languages like PHP and JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php

What exactly is the meaning of bind and binding in PHP and JavaScript programming? For example in PHP the `mysqli_stmt::bind_param -- mysqli_stmt_bind_param`:

> binds variables to a prepared statement as parameters.

What does this mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can think of a prepared statement as some kind of function; it is ready to be executed once it knows what its parameters are. With the bind function, you tell the statement what the value is for those parameters. Then you call the execute function which actually executes the statement.

The advantage of the binding functions is that they will take care of any possible hacking attempts by SQL injection, and escape characters like the quote (`'`) which would often lead to invalid SQL statements. Furthermore, you can reuse existing prepared statements by binding them again.

(Note that this only involves PHP - JavaScript plays no role in this as that is executed on the client side.)